# bxSlider: Disabling touchEnabled for desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I am trying to disable the touchEnabled option for the bxSlider library if the user has a desktop browser.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome|Mozilla|Safari/)){
     $('.theSlider').bxSlider({
          touchEnabled: false
     });
}

//Html slider
<ul class="theSlider">
```

When debugging in the developer tools console in Chrome I get touchEnabled is not defined when trying to set it to false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **What** is `undefined`? How do you inspect it?

Comment: @Quentin I was debugging in Chrome. The if statement returns true, and it can find the `$('.theSlider').bxSlider`. So my best guess is that touchEnabled is undefined somehow.

Comment: "in Chrome" is very vague. What, precisely, is `undefined`? Where do you see `undefined` displayed? Perhaps a screenshot of your developer tools (is it in the developer tools you see that?) would help?

Comment: @Quentin In the developer tools console I am typing 
`if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome|Mozilla|Safari/)) {
    $('.theSlider').bxSlider({touchEnabled : false});                
}` and the error message I am getting now is touchEnabled is not defined.

Comment: @user3586417 Like most jQuery plugins, bxSlider must be reloaded in order to change options, it cannot change them "on the fly" AFAIK. See my answer for possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, this is the solution I managed to work out. I set a default var touchDevice as false. If the user is using a mobile device it detects and sets touchDevice to true. When I initialise the bxSlider it will take whatever touchDevice is set to, and set touchEnabled to that result.

```
// Enable touch events for Mobile Browsers
var touchDevice = false;
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/)) {
      touchDevice = true;
}

$('.theSlider').bxSlider({
      touchEnabled: touchDevice
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Listen for [`touchstart` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart) on the window object. If app loads on a desktop, most likely it doesn't fire off touch events. Inversely a mobile device will trigger a touchstart event with normal use.
2. Next, if and when `touchstart` fires, bx method [`.reloadSlider()`](http://bxslider.com/options#reloadSlider) runs and passes the object that stores the new options (`cfg2`)
3. The last task is to remove the listener since a purpose such as this is only needed once per session.

**Details are commented within demo**

### Demo

```js
// Initial Configuration
var cfg1 = {
  touchEnabled: false
}
// Alternate Configuration
var cfg2 = {
  touchEnabled: true,
  oneToOneTouch: true,
  swipeThreshold: 25,
  preventDefaultSwipeX: false,
  preventDefaultSwipeY: false
}

/* Store the instant in a variable.
|| Pass the cfg1 option 
*/
var bx = $('.bx').bxSlider(cfg1);

/* Delegate the touchstart event on window object
|| which basically will only detects a touchstart
|| event if the device can actually use touch events.
|| So when using a laptop, desktop, etc., the 
|| touchstart will never be triggered.
*/
/* Now if this loads on a mobile device, it will detect
|| touchstart event and then reload bxSlider with a new
|| configuration (cfg2) which among its options is the
|| touchEnabled: true / property: value
|| Once that is done, it will remove the event listener
|| with .off() method.
*/
$(window).on('touchstart', enableTouch);

function enableTouch(e) {

  bx.reloadSlider(cfg2);

  $(window).off('touchstart', enableTouch);
}
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class='bx'>
  <li><img src='http://imgh.us/1one.png'></li>
  <li><img src='http://imgh.us/2two.png'></li>
  <li><img src='http://imgh.us/3three.png'></li>
  <li><img src='http://imgh.us/4four.png'></li>
  <li><img src='http://imgh.us/5five.png'></li>
  <li><img src='http://imgh.us/6six.png'></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js'></script>
```